# Scan Java classpath for lone subclass?

Tags: java, reflection, classpath, classloader, war

I have a rather unique situation where I know my Java web app will always be packaged with 1-and-only-1 concrete subclass of an `AbstractWidget`:

```
public abstract class AbstractWidget {
    // ...
}

public class SimpleWidget extends AbstractWidget {
    // ...
}

public class ComplexWidget extends AbstractWidget {
    // ...
}

public class CrazyComplexWidget extends AbstractWidget {
    // ...
}

// ...etc.
```

Again, I know at runtime that my `WAR/WEB-INF/classes` directory will always have 1-and-only-1 `AbstractWidget` impl packaged in it (no more, no less), be it `ComplexWidget.class`, `SimpleWidget.class`, etc.

I'm trying to construct code (that would actually run when the WAR starts up from inside its `ServletContextListener` impl) that would be able to scan the runtime classpath and obtain an instance (**using public no-arg constructor**) of the `AbstractWidget`.

Thus, if my WAR has:

```
myWar/
    WEB-INF/
        lib/
        classes/
            com/
                myorg/
                    App (implements ServletContextListener)
                    ... lots of other classes and packages
                    some/
                        arbitrary/
                            package/
                                SimpleWidget
```

Then, from inside `App#contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent)` I need code that will find `SimpleWidget.class` on the classpath and give me an instance of it:

```
public class App implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Scan classpath for the lone AbstractWidget impl somehow.
        ???

        // Use public, no-arg ctor to instantiate the impl.
        AbstractWidget widget = ???

        // Now do stuff with widget...
    }
}
```

I know you can use reflection methods like `Class.isAssignableFrom()`, but not sure if that is the correct way to go, and even if it is, how to use it for my given use case. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the names of the subclasses beforehand?

Comment: Thanks @Joni (+1) - No, thats my hangup. I need a way to *describe* a class that extends `AbstractWidget` and search for it. Again, there will only be 1 of these such classes.

Comment: I was thinking I might have to resort to annotations, but if I can avoid them I would prefer to.

Comment: How do you know there will be only one, is it included by an external process? Could the same process add the name of the subclass in a configuration file?

Comment: Thanks again @Joni (+1) - yes an external process packages up the WAR (and guarantees me that 1 and only 1 subclass will be included *somewhere* in the classpath). And yes, this external process *could* include a config file with the subclass' name, but this would be **extremely painful** (the external process is a legacy system and we don't have the source code for it anymore). So I wouldn't want to have to explore that option unless it truly was my 1 and only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [the reflections api.](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/)  It has utilities for finding the subclass(es) of a given class.  You can do something like this with it:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections();
Set<Class<? extends AbstractWidget>> subclasses;
subclasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(AbstractWidget.class);
```

This will get you a `Set` containing all the subclasses of the `AbstractWidget` class on the classpath. http://code.google.com/p/reflections/

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very old question but ClassGraph library can help you very easily get all classes in the classpath extending a given class, basically all subclasses of a given class.

Gradle dependency

```
compile group: 'io.github.classgraph', name: 'classgraph', version: '4.8.46'
```

This how you can easily you can scan classpath

```
ScanResult scanResult = new ClassGraph()
    .whitelistPackages("com.myorg") //whatever package you want to scan
    .verbose()
    .enableAllInfo() 
    .scan();

System.out.println("Classes which extending '" + AbstractWidget.class.getSimpleName() + "' class");
ClassInfoList classInfoList = scanResult.getSubclasses(AbstractWidget.class.getName());
for (ClassInfo classInfo : classInfoList) {
    System.out.println("\t" + classInfo.getName());
}
```

Output assuming you have SimpleWidget class in the classpath

```
Classes which extending 'AbstractWidget' class
    com.myorg.some.arbitrary.package.SimpleWidget
```

I hope it helps. ClassGraph is really powerful library and can do much more this simple need. Its explain really well in this article https://readtorakesh.com/java-classpath-scanning-using-classgraph/